# Генерируются точки на графике CanvasJS, как их потом убрать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

У меня есть алгоритм который генерирует точки от центра во все стороны (CanvasJS + React). Подскажите пожалуйста, как их можно потом убрать в таком же порядке как они и появлялись на графике?

```
for (let i = 1; i < Points; i++) {

        let newX = data[i - 1].x  + Math.random() * (Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1) * var;
        let newY = data[i - 1].y  + Math.random() * (Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1) * var;
        data.push({ x: newX, y: newY }); 
        var += Math.random(0,1)*2;
      }

    return data;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (data.length) {
  data.splice(data.length - 1, 1);
}
```

---

А, пардон. Первые сорок точек:

```
var i = 0;
while (i++ < 40 && data.length) {
  data.splice(0, 1);
}
```

или в одну строчку

```
data.splice(0, Math.min(40, data.length));
```

Comment: Igor, большое спасибо. Последний вопрос: хочу поместить мой первый код в if statement и потом интегрировать data.slice(). Как будет правильно написать if(state.draw === "yes") {....} пишет что state not defined, но я хочу сделать импорт state из другой функции. Спасибо !!

Comment: @Johnny Мало кода. Попробуйте задать новый вопрос, куда включите код, имеющий отношение к новой проблеме.

Comment: Igor, попробовал данный код, но к сожалению он не работает. Скажите, есть ли какой-то способ убрать первый 40 точек? Когда использовал алгоритм pop() , точки удивлялись справа налево, а не в каком-то порядке. Shift() и Slice() тоже не работают